# rmd will automatically create code chunks when pressed "i"

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am a new R markdown user. I am facing this issue in which whenever I type "i", new code chunk gets created automatically. I tried restarting R studio and even updated it but to no avail.

Comment: If you go to "Tools...Modify Keyboard Shortcuts" and search for "Insert Chunk", what does it show? The default seems to be "ctrl+alt+i". Your control and alt keys aren't being pressed, right? What version of Rstudio are you running?

Comment: Hey, I don't know how but "i" got added as a shortcut to insert chunk. I changed it. Thank you very much.